# PHP XML IE problem

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<NBR>
    <resultGroups>
    <result>Hello</result> 
    </resultGroups>
</NBR>
```

i have a n xml created in PHP ike this. i am retruning this XML into javascript and is trying to acces the value of node "result" using

```
alert($(xmlObj).children('result').text());
```

In firefox its working fine. but in IE it gives out nothing...

how can i solve this???

Comment: Maybe this should read: "IE Problem: Doesn't follow standards" :-)

Comment: does the file have a .xml file extension? IE has issues if the extension doesn't match the actual file type.

Comment: @Jweede - yeah i agree. today i just met a "IE7 doesn't eat cookies" problem. it just simply rejected my PHP app's cookies!

Answer (score 1):

It could be you are not sending the correct XML Content-Type header. You should send `Content-Type: text/xml` with XML content. You should also check that you set the correct charset in both the headers and the file. IE should be able to parse a correct XML response just fine if the JS code is correct and your XML response is valid.

Comment: make sure that it is the very first part of the reponse, otherwise the header will have already been set to something else.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would that is has something to do with the **text()** function. I am a Prototype guy myself but I ran into a similar problem with IE a little while ago. It came from me trying to pull the *textContent* value from an element in the DOM. I could grab the value in all other browser but IE was giving me the shaft. After running some tests, this is what I came up with:

IE does not support **element.textContent**. In most browsers, like FireFox, you would be able to pull the *textContent* value from *element*.

**Example**

```
<p id="my_element">this is my element</p>
alert($('my_element').textContent); // will alert "this is my element"
```

In IE, you need to use *element.innerHTML*. This will return the value you want. Right now, I assume that **text()** is returning the *textContent* value  and that is why you're getting no dice.

**Example**

```
<p id="my_element">this is my element</p>
alert($('my_element').innerHTML); // will alert "this is my element"
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Are you loading this across SSL?

There is a known issue in IE where sometimes it fails to load XML over SSL:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;272359

This page contains more info on how to resolve it:

http://www.blog.lessrain.com/flash-nasty-xml-load-bug-in-internet-explorer/

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your in your headers that you're specifying the `Content-Type` *and* `charset`, and that your charset (if using utf-8) is **utf-8** and *not* **utf8**. IE doesn't recognise the latter and doesn't bother to tell you.

So, you want your header to specify the following:

```
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried parsing the data out before alert'ing it, and possibly using find instead?

```
var node_text = $(xmlObj).find('result').text();
alert(node_text);
```

Otherwise i would suggest trying to change the result tag to something different (like **theresult**) - everyone knows IE likes to do strange things! :)

Answer (score 0):

If <result> is inside <resultGroups>, then try:

```
alert($(xmlObj).children('resultGroups').children('result').text());
```

or, you could try:

```
alert($($($(xmlObj).children('resultGroups')).children('result')).text());
```

or even:

```
alert($($(xmlObj).children('result')).text());
```

Let me know if any of these work.

Comment: You are just creating multiple jQuery objects and gaining no real value from it.

Comment: He could be using Prototype. If he is using Prototype, it is suggested that you do it like I said, on the guide: http://www.prototypejs.org/learn/extensions (at the bottom)